# DevPartner: "Collect from .NET". VS "Collect COM information"

Tags: devpartner

I downloaded and installed official trial version of DevPartner v110300. According to documentation (that accompanies installation) in project properties property "Collect from .NET" should exist. But I have "Collect COM information" for native C++, managed C++ and for **C#** projects. I use Visual Studio 2012. What's the reason? How to resolve?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at page 115 of Understanding Devpartner you will see that collect .Net is a solution property and not a project property.

You need to select the solution node and not the project node. It should be set to true by default.[image]

Comment: Mark is being modest, but he is one of the main developers for MicroFocus Devpartner Studio.